# How to setup audio session for alarm ringtones in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, just-audio

I am creating an alarm clock application, using [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) to play the alarm ringtones and [audio_session](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_session) to configure the audio type. Without configuring the audio, the app uses the media volume for the audio. I want the app to tell the system that this is an alarm audio, so it uses the system alarm volume for the ringtones and play it even in DnD etc.

#### What I have tried

Here is the setup that I currently have:

```dart
// Configuring audio session using audio_session
final session = await AudioSession.instance;
await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration(
  androidAudioAttributes: AndroidAudioAttributes(
    flags: AndroidAudioFlags.audibilityEnforced,
    usage: AndroidAudioUsage.alarm,
  ),
));

// Initializing and playing the audio using just_audio
player = AudioPlayer();
await player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(ringtoneUri));
await player.setLoopMode(loopMode);
player.play();
```

On some devices that I have tested (Android 6 and 8), it uses the phone ringtone volume, while on others (Android 11), it correctly uses the alarm volume.

What is the correct method to do it, so it uses the alarm volume on all devices?

Comment: I think you would be better off asking your question in terms of the native platform API - one question for Android and another question for iOS, since this flutter package simply mirrors the native APIs. You are unlikely to find someone who is an expert in Flutter and an expert in the iOS AVAudioSession API and an expert in the Android AudioManager API. That is what I already suggested when you opened an issue on GitHub.

Comment: (And, since those two questions would be more narrow, it's also more likely that those two specific questions would have already been asked and answered somewhere on StackOverflow.)

Comment: @RyanHeise Well actually, I am not really interested in iOS, don't know why I tagged that... I'll edit the question. I have seen the existing questions regarding native android API to set the alarm channel and I have tried to mirror that here. I am more interested in finding out whether my use and initialization of the two packages is correct or not.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, it was the `audibilityEnforced` flag which can cause this issue on some devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was the `AndroidAudioFlags.audibilityEnforced` flag, which seems to be pretty unrealiable, and can cause differing behavior on different devices. Removing it causes the volume to be controlled by alarm stream volume.

Android Docs: [`FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED`](https://source.android.com/docs/core/audio/attributes#flags)

#### Working code

```dart
final session = await AudioSession.instance;
await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration(
  androidAudioAttributes: AndroidAudioAttributes(
    usage: AndroidAudioUsage.alarm,
  ),
));

// Initializing and playing the audio using just_audio
player = AudioPlayer();
await player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(ringtoneUri));
await player.setLoopMode(loopMode);
player.play();
```

Comment: P.S. You can mark your own answer as the accepted answer so that this question becomes registered as "answered".